# Why doesn't the MathOverflow account appear?

Tags: support, status-completed, network-profile, mathoverflow

MathOverflow is now upgraded to Stack Exchange 2.0.

So why doesn't [my MathOverflow account](https://mathoverflow.net/users/34538/sebastien-palcoux) appear on my accounts page?

Comment: Did you associate the account? please post a link. EDIT never mind I found you.

Comment: Related: [Why are MO accounts not listed among other SE accounts?](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/58/why-are-mo-accounts-not-listed-among-other-se-accounts)

Comment: Yep, that pretty much explains it.

Comment: @animuson actually this one is dupe of that question, too bad it's on other site. :)

Comment: Known bug, wait a few days

Comment: People at MO don't want others to know they hang out there? ;-)

Comment: Appears to be fixed now.

Comment: Yes it's ok. Thanks to the people who fixed this problem !