# Make the per site profile pages show network outage message instead of `area 51` link

Tags: feature-request, bug

Makes me sad that I can't navigate to different sites from my account listing, so sad I didn't even include any freehand circles. :-(

[image]

First shot from SO, second from Meta.

As @Sha pointed out its a temporary network glitch, and you can see the error message in the linked to question "temporarily unavailable."

To avoid confusion in the future I propose that this message also be shown on individual site profile pages. I think this makes much more sense then just showing me `Area 51`.

Comment: See [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/440462/ryan?tab=accounts) it says "Account information is temporarily unavailable" - temp glitch, it will sort itself out soon.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm able to see your different accounts. So it must be a temporary glitch.

Comment: Ah, @ShaWizDowArd thanks. Also sad everything on the network profile is unavailable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Network Profile information reporting 'temporarily unavailable'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118201/network-profile-information-reporting-temporarily-unavailable)

Comment: @Sai only the top 5 which are cached in different place.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd and see I didn't check the network profile page, maybe it should show that message (as Nick so nicely pointed out) on our profile page so that if we don't check the network profile page we can still know it's a network glitch and not the site blowing up.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd oh ok. that makes more sense.

Comment: @ryan it's taking the data from different place (which isn't always affected by those outages) but yeah, valid request. Feel free to ask Nick here.

Answer (score 5):

We are performing network maintenance after the import of https://mathoverflow.net/.  Hang on and this will resolve itself when the backfill completes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Nick. I changed the question to be a feature request to avoid future confusion.

Comment: Fixing [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186603/152859) I guess? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yup